# HTML - Por que usar, ou não usar, " /> " para fechar tags sem conteúdo?

Tags: html, html5, xhtml

Reparei que é comum ver algumas tags de elementos do tipo *Void* com o fechamento **`/>`**

Ex:

```
<br />
<hr/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="pt.stackoverflow.com"/>
```

E aqui mesmo no fonte do StackOverflow achei `<input>` com e sem o fechamento da tag...

Ex:

```
<input id="author" name="author" type="text">
<input type="submit" id="pin-site-btn" value="Adicionar" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Pelo que vi, parece que no HTML5 o Browser ignora essa <kbd>/</kbd> nas tags que não precisam ser fechadas como as citadas acima. *(Diferente da Div por exemplo que deve ser fechada `<div>...</div>`)*

Então se o Browser ignora isso, e se o uso não é obrigatório, por que é tão comum ver [void-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) fechados dessa forma <kbd>/ ></kbd> sem motivo aparente?

OBS: No Materialize mesmo, na Configuração de HTML, tem **`<link>`** com e sem <kbd>/ ></kbd> http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

*Referencia W3C Void Elements:* https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements

Answer (score 1):

A ideia de fechar as tags sem filhos vem do XML, numa proposta de unificar as duas linguagens criando a XHTML. Entretanto, pelo que sei isso não foi pra frente - nem esse requisito foi adotado no HTML5.

Desse modo, fechar essas tags não é obrigatório, mas é opcional caso você deseje fazê-lo. Eu sempre faço, por "estética" mesmo, mas não é necessário.

(Cabe lembrar que, se a tag não for uma das listadas como "sem filhos", não fechar é sim um erro - ainda que os browsers "se virem" para interpretar o conteúdo pra você. Mas nesse caso, o fechamento deve-se dar por uma tag de fechamento distinta)

Trecho do nosso colega: mgibsonbr aqui da StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

O fechamento de tags vem do HTML5, portanto, caso esteja desenvolvendo um site usando HTML5, é importante fechar as tags. É importante desenvolver já com o padrão do HTML5 pois pode ser que os navegadores deixem de dar suporte a versões antigas do HTML, deixando assim obrigatório o uso do fechamento de tags.

Comment: Na verdade é ao contrário, a `/>` é uma "prática" no HTML4x e não do HTML5, então se no futuro der algum problema é pelo fato de estar usando. A recomendação HTML é que não use, mesmo assim a gente encontra esse fechamento para todo lado...